# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when using pd.read_excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This error keeps popping up when I try to create a DataFrame out of a .xls file. Here's my code:

```
energy = pd.read_excel('Energy indicators.xls', sheetname='Energy', header=16, skip_footer=246, index_col=2, na_values='...')
```

Which results in the error: 
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried removing all the optional arguments?

Comment: If this is for the coursera project, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036296/using-read-excel-with-converters-for-reading-excel-file-into-pandas-dataframe-re